# How to add box shadow for highchart chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I want to have the following style on my chart border

```
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
border: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
```

There is shadow property for the chart but it doesn't seem to work, can someone point out my mistake?

Thanks

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myduLmcf/)

Edit: I want it to look like this

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to apply the styles to the chart container?  What selector are you using for your style rule?

Comment: Check my updated answer. Just increase or descrease `width` value until you get the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `shadow`, `offsetX` and `offsetY` to a number instead of string:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        shadow: {
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
            offsetX: 1,
            offsetY: 1,
            opacity: '0.1',
            width: 10
        }
    }
});
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myduLmcf/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just apply it to the container? Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myduLmcf/2)

```
#container {
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
}
```